# While running the Cucumber test throws error and undefined implement with the following snippet

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

While running the Cucumber/javascript/selenium web driver test, I am getting an `Undefined. Implement with the following snippet: this.Then(/^I should display "([^"]*)" under the search area$/, function (arg1, callback){ callback(null, 'pending');....`. While typing the text in the search area, system will display a list of results under the search input box. Out of the results displaying, I am looking for an element with text 'Building Designers'. Any idea why this is throwing as undefined ?

```
Feature: Test search 
   Scenario: List all the items based on input text provide in search
        When I typed the following "Building" text in input
        Then I should display "Building Designers" under the search area
```

// search-steps.js

```
this.When(/^I typed the following "([^"]*)" text in input$/, (text) =>{
      return helpers.loadPage('https://www.sometestsite.com')    
      .then(()=>{
          driver.findElement(By.id('search')).sendKeys(text);
      })
    })



this.Then(/^I should display "([^"]*)"under the search area&/, function (mytxt){
        return driver.wait(until.elementsLocated(By.cssSelector("div.SearchResults--result.button")), 50000).getText().then(el => {
        console.log("print text here:"+el);
        const displayTxt = el;  
        expect(displayTxt).to.be.eql(mytxt);        
        });     
    })
```

[image]

Comment: why do you use 'this.When' ? add:  const { Before, Given, When, Then } = require('cucumber')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
this.Then(/^I should display "([^"]*)"under the search area&/, function (mytxt){
```

You have an & instead of a $ at the end